# Increase ext4 partition size by decreasing Swap memory size in linux

Tags: linux, memory

I was a newbie while installing linux mint 17.2 in my laptop. So I allocated more than 20GB for my swap memory and 30Gb for ext4 partition. Now only I realized that swap memory is using instead of RAM while running memory overwhelming applications.I have 4GB of DDR3 RAM so no need of this much of swap memory.So I want to add some memory space from swap to Ext4. Is there any idea for deleting or decreasing the swap memory and add that memory to EXT4 partition? 
The details of my hard disk given bellow .I'm using Linux mint 17.2 64 bit and windows 8 pro with media center 64 bit in dual boot.

```
$parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54757 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs            boot
2      106MB   210GB  210GB   primary   ntfs
3      210GB   421GB  211GB   primary   ntfs
4      421GB   750GB  329GB   extended                  lba
7      421GB   451GB  30.0GB  logical   ext4
8      451GB   473GB  22.4GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
5      473GB   579GB  106GB   logical   ntfs
6      579GB   750GB  171GB   logical   ntfs

(parted)
```

If the solution will not effect my windows files then let me know the solution. Actually I found some solutions but most of them are suggesting 'GParted ISO '.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate to the related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com/  or http://askubuntu.com/ . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved my problem,
 I installed GParted ISO and first turned of the swap memory and edit the swap partition.
so the unpartitioned space is increased and then I selected my ext4 partition and add the unpartitioned space to ext4 . then save the process. Now everything is working good.
and thank you shellter for your suggession .